# Play framework with scala image upload server error

Tags: scala, playframework, image-uploading, dokku

When I upload images localhost there is no problem on uploading. 
But when deployed on server (dokku on digitalocean) server returns error 500 with NoSuchFile exception. What is my mistake?

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
      request.body.file("file").map { picture =>
         import java.io.File
         val filename = picture.filename
         val extension = Files.getFileExtension(filename)
         val contentType = picture.contentType
         Logger.warn(extension)
         val newFileName = s"${UUID.randomUUID}.$extension"
         val uniqueFile = new File(s"public/pictures/$newFileName")
         picture.ref.moveTo(uniqueFile)
         Ok(newFileName)
  }.getOrElse {
         Ok("error")
  }
}
```

error log:

> @6oo5djflc - Internal server error, for (POST) [/template/uploadLogo]
>
> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected
>   exception[NoSuchFileException:
>   /tmp/playtemp71801546008559360/multipartBody6913035116351905525asTemporaryFile
>   -> public/pictures/1046fe85-d910-41f4-a52f-53a6f2506d76.png]

Comment: Does the destination directory exists? Also, use your public directory (or any other inside the application directory) to store uploaded files is a bad idea. What happens the next time you deploy a new version of your application?

Comment: Yes, i changed file upload method to the amazon s3

Answer (score 0):

For those ending up here, adding `application.root` in front of the path of `new File(..)` solved the problem for me, i.e.

`new File(s"${application.path}/the_actual_filename.jpg")`